# Writing a tail -f python script that doesn't utilize 100% CPU

Tags: python, algorithm

Here's a simple implementation of tail -f written in python. The problem with this is with the looping nature, this script likes to hog a lot of the CPU time. If it's something one would like to run as a forked process/daemon, it would be an inefficient start.

What's a solution to have a CPU efficient tail -f written in Python?

```
    # CPU inefficient tail -f 
    def main():
     filename = '/tmp/foo'
     file = open(filename, 'r')
     st_results = os.stat(filename)
     st_size = st_results[6]
     file.seek(st_size)
     lastmatch = 0

     while 1:
       where = file.tell()
       line = file.readline()
       if not line:
         time.sleep(1)
         file.seek(where)
       else:
         print line,
```

Comment: Really, even with the sleep(1), it's hogging the CPU? Is that file being continuously written to? Something you may want to consider, it's generally okay for a process to use most of the CPU, especially if the other processes don't need it. Otherwise, it's wasted (battery life on portable devices are the exception there, however).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an implementation that's going to be extremely efficient AND portable between Windows on one side, and just about every other system on the other. Just about everywhere, I'd use the `select` module of the standard library (which can be based on system level functionality such as select, kqueue, etc) to get woken up when and only when there are changes to a file, without polling; but on Windows select can only work on sockets. So, on Windows, I'd use directory change notifications instead (e.g. via ctypes or win32).